# axios taking too long to fetch data some time it just doesn't fetch

Tags: heroku, axios

I have hosted my expressjs in Heroku and I know the Heroku goes to sleep after 30 min. But the problem here is that the APIs are not even getting fetched after 2-3 times of reloading. Sometimes it loads sometimes it does not. Even when it loads it takes about 20-40 seconds.

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://ask-over.herokuapp.com/questapi").then((result) => {
      // console.table(result.data);
      setItems(result.data);
    });
  }, []);
```

This is the site

https://wixten.com/

[image]

pls check this in postman u can see its takes about 10 secs sometimes more to load

https://ask-over.herokuapp.com/questapi

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you see in the [Heroku logs](https://help.heroku.com/UMAUQ4UF/why-am-i-seeing-application-error)?

Comment: how can i check that?

Comment: The first step is to install the [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli). Next, use the CLI to [log in to Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#getting-started). Finally, use the CLI to issue the `heroku logs --tail` command to see what's happening in your app.

Comment: i have added the scrren shot of heroku logs there i didnot find any error but my  get metthod is too slow

Comment: @jisaks I have tested your api it's giving response as normal. There might be some issue with your react app logic or see in your network tab, make your it's showing  Fast 3G.

Comment: i changed to fast 3g still there is issue

Comment: i have posted the screen shot showing the time taken